# change naming convention of the url

Tags: php, laravel, url, url-routing, slug

I want to change the naming convention of the following url :

```
http://example.org/designs/CV%20Designs
```

To be the following:

```
http://example.org/designs/cv-designs
```

Here is my web.php route file:

```
    Route::get('designs/{design}', 'DesignsController@show')
        ->name('designs.show');
```

And here is my Design Model:

```
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        $slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');
        dd($slug);
        return 'designName';
    }
```

When I dd(slug); the output is 'Laravel 5 Framework' but I want it to be designName

Comment: Welcome to SO ... so you basically want to use a "slug"?

Comment: @lagbox Yes Please

Comment: You can look at \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug() https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-slug

Comment: @KurtFriars I did look at it but the problem is that I dont know how to pass the design name instead of 'Laravel 5 Framework' in the following line. 

$slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to generate the url?

Comment: Show your blade code

Comment: Here is my web.php route file:

`Route::get('designs/{design}', 'DesignsController@show')->name('designs.show');
`

And here is my Design Model:

`public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        $slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');
        dd($slug);
        return 'designName';
    }`

when I `dd(slug);` the output is  'Laravel 5 Framework' but I want it to be designName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I am going to make some assumptions here, but lets say you have this function on your Design model:

Design.php

```
class Design extends Model
{
    ...

    /**
     * Assuming you dont have a slug column on your designs table
     *
     * Also assuming the slug is built from a column called 'name' on
     * your designs table
     */
    public function getSlugAttribute()
    {
        return \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($this->name);
    }
    
    // This assumes there is a column on posts table of 'design_id'
    public function posts()
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now let's make an example of how you can build the desired route.

**EDIT**

Through further discussions with the asker, they wan't to show all Posts related to the Design they are showing (See model above). The setup in this answer is suitable for that, and you can refer to the show method defined below.
Assume we have `DesignsController.php`:

```
class DesignsController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function index()
    {
        return view('designs.index', [
            'designs' => Design::all(),
        ]);
    }

    public function show(Request $request, string $design)
    {
        // It is worth noting here if name has a double space you wont
        // be able to build backwards to it for a query
        // ie) Design\s\sOne !== $lower(Design\sOne)\

        $spaced = str_replace('-', ' ', $design);
        $lower = strtolower($spaced);
        $design = Design::with('posts')->whereRaw("LOWER(name) = '$lower'")->first();
        
        return view('designs.show', [
            'design' => $design,
        ]);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now in the 'designs/index.blade.php' file you could do something like:

```
    @foreach($designs as $design)
        <a href="{{ route('designs.show', [ 'design' => $design->slug ]) }}">{{ $design->name }}</a>
    @endforeach
```

That would list all of your designs by name, linked to the designs.show route by their slug.

If you would always like the slug value to be loaded [when serializing](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) to an array or json, you can add it to the protected $appends array on the model.

If you don't ALWAYS want it appended, you need to append it at run time using for example `$design->append('slug')`.

Or if you have a collection of Designs you can do `$designs->each->append('slug')`.

Now in your designs.show blade file you can, access the Design's posts using the relation we loaded using Design::with('posts'), by doing the following:

```
    @foreach ($design->posts as $post)
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$post->postImage) }}">
    @endforeach
```

Comment: the problem is that when I create 2 designs with the same name the posts show on both of them even though they shouldnt since the designs have different ids

Comment: Oh Ok Thanks man, I will just continue using the id as the url